# Is there a way to indent a chunk of code?

Tags: discussion, support, code-formatting

When formatting a question, I usually copy and paste the code that I want examined. But it is somewhat cumbersome to have to indent every line of code by 4 spaces, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

For example, in some programming languages, one can highlight any code in a program and then press the tab key to indent the entire thing. Is there a similar feature in SO?

If not, I think this would be a pretty neat feature to facilitate the formatting of a question.

Comment: CTRL-k applied to selected code lines usually serves well for me.

Comment: The tooltip for the **{ }** button in the editor toolbar tells you what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little bit more of a workaround that a full blown feature, but you can just put a non-indented character in it, and then use the code sample button.

that button in the functions bar above the text area you're typing in.  It's icon looks like this:  `{}`

**so if you have code like this**

```
public static void foo()
{
int i = 1;
int b = 2;
}
```

**first, change it to this**

```
    public static void foo()
    {
//placeholder
    int i = 1;
    int b = 2;
    }
```

**and then select the placeholder and the code you want to indent and format it as code**

```
public static void foo()
{
//placeholder
    int i = 1;
    int b = 2;
}
```

**and then remove the placeholder**

```
public static void foo()
{
    int i = 1;
    int b = 2;
}
```

or, you can just not indent at all when you write the code, and start formatting it as code from the inside-out using the same concept.

Comment: If the OP is just copy and pasting code. It's probably indented but does not have the initial indentation to make it a code block. In that case highlighting all the code and doing **Ctrl+K** is probably easier.

Comment: **Ctrl-K is useless** if you're putting code inside a list item or a blockquote

Answer (score 18):

- Put your cursor at the start of the line you want to unindent (some users call it shift and un-shift).
- Select all lines you want to unindent / shift
- Press Ctrl+K as many times as needed
- Remove the (annoyingly) added white line at the top of your selection.

Or if you're into animated gifs:

> [image]

Comment: omg thanks, I was forever c&p'ing code into a text editor to de-indent it.

Comment: @user438383: Me too. I feel stupid for not knowing this, or looking up whether it might possible. I pretty consistently fix indentation issues, at least when I'm on a desktop, and it's a bit of a tedious process. Glad to learn this!

Comment: I have [a web application for that](https://pmortensen.eu/world/Text.php) (button *"Remove common leading space"*), mostly used as a part of automation (macro keyboard - and the WordPress overhead can be [turned off](https://pmortensen.eu/world/Text.php?OverflowStyle=Native)). Inline JavaScript would be much faster, though.